# References for Shravan Maas Puja (श्रावण मास पूजा)

Tags: shiva, puranas, puja, agamas, vrata

The time for Shravan maas is nearby. And the eagerness in the masses will spark to worship Shiva.

Is Shravan archana for Shiva mentioned in any Shastra like Purana, Itihasa or any Shaiva agamas? Or is it Lokachara?

Also are there any rules & rituals prescribed for the archana-vidhi in Shastras, like any peetha puja, parthivlingarchana, or special invocations for Shravana maas in particular?

(**Ps**- Please do not quote from blogs, Wikipedia or Jyotish shastra that states, why one should fast in Shravan. Since I'm looking for a staunch shastra pramana for archana vidhi.)

Comment: I think asking two questions separately is recommended: One for reference from scriptures and another for the rules.

Comment: @hanugm Usually if a vrata is mentioned in any Shastra, then it comes with vidhan prescribed in same or next chapter. Thus, I didn't give a second tght to put both questions togethar 

Comment: Okay. I think I came across this in Shiv Puran. If time allows, I will check.

Comment: @hanugm will be much obliged.

Comment: Please refre to "chatur mass mahatmya" in skand puran......

Comment: @Himanshu srry for late reply. Yet it would be great if you cited the referances as it is frm Skanda puran & compile it in an answer format ;)